# Bitbucket pipeline condition to cd into folder and run commands

Tags: bitbucket, bitbucket-pipelines, bitbucket-server, bitbucket-cloud

Is there a way with Bitbucket Pipeline condition to cd into specific folder and execute commands? My idea is to have folder with Terraform project and environment (develop, staging and prod). Here is what I have as bitbucket repository structure:

myproject:

```
 - /infra/prod/main.tf 
 - /infra/staging/main.tf
 - /infra/develop/main.tf
```

My step:

```
  - step: 
  name: Terraform initialization and plan
  image: hashicorp/terraform
  script: 
      - cd myproject # cd to the specific environment folder
      - terraform init
      - terraform plan -var-file="my-variables.tfvars"
  condition:
    changesets:
      includePaths:
        - "myproject/**" # Running the step this way only check for changes in the root folder of myproject/
```

Regards,
Ivo

Answer (score 0):

It seems the solution was simple but for some reason VS code didn't update my Bitbucket repository folder names for the environment. The code below helped me to achieve what I want with parameters for each environment

image: docker:stable

```
pipelines:
  custom:
      Terraform:
      - variables: 
          - name: ENVIRONMENT
            default: dev
            allowed-values:
             - dev
             - staging
             - prod
          - name: ACTION
            default: "apply"
            allowed-values: 
             - apply
      - step: 
          name: Terraform initialization and plan
          image: hashicorp/terraform
          script: 
              - cd infra/$ENVIRONMENT
              - terraform init
              - terraform plan -var-file="my-variables.tfvars"
          condition:
            changesets:
              includePaths:
                - "infra/dev/**"
                - "infra/staging/**"
                - "infra/prod/**"
```